# Add number of hours to Time type

Tags: sql, time

How can I add a decimal number of hours to a Time type?

For example, 10:00 + 1.5 = 11:30.

Comment: Do you want to add 1.5 hours to the time? What version of Sql are you using?

Comment: Does 1.5 represent hours then? What if you wrap past 23:59:59.99999999? keep adding or lose the overflow?

Comment: gbn's question is important -- keep in mind Time in SQL is a wall-clock time, not a TimeSpan like in C#.

Answer (score 3):

If on Microsoft SQL Server...

```
declare @t time
set @t = '10:00:00'
set @t = dateadd(mi, 1.5*60, @t)
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

However, this is very dependent on your database system. Each system has its own mechanism for date addition.

Comment: should be `set @t = '00:00:00'` because 5,5 = 05:30

Comment: @vakio Not sure what you mean, but OP stated he wanted to add 1.5 hours to 10:00. Thus @t is initialized to OP's time.

Comment: You would need to use minutes & 1.5 * 60 as 1.5 would be cast to int so interpreted as 1

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that whatever RDBMS you're using won't know what units your `1.5` is in (years? hours? minutes? seconds?).  There are ways to add intervals of time (eg 1.5 hours) to a timestamp.  The syntax is dependent on the RDBMS that you're using.